# Missing value imputation for categorical dataset which is already label encoded

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, data-imputation

I have a doubt regarding **categorical data encoding, and, missing value imputation.**.

Say, I have a categorical dataset whose one of the attributes is gender. The attribute is consist of two values male and female. There are some missing values on this attribute.
The dataset is coming with pre-processed encoding techniques. Such as, I know the gender has two values male and female but when I downloaded the dataset from data repository the gender is already labeled encoded as 1 and 2. The dataset has missing values.

The problem in this scenario is  I can not use mode imputation technique in the dataset beacuse it is already label encoded.

If I try to use the mean method for imputing the missing values the imputation produced a new fractional category for gender which is a superficial category.

What I am trying to say is that, gender has three values after imputation, they are 1, 0.6589, 2.

What will be the technique to handle the situation?

Comment: 1) Do you want to use a single imputation approach, or a multiple imputation approach?  2) Why can't you use mode imputation? The mode of a binary category is the most frequent category. The fact that the data is labelled as "1" and "2" instead of "female" and "male" is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I cannot understand what do you want to imply `The fact that the data is labelled as "1" and "2" instead of "female" and "male" is irrelevant. ` I did not labelled it as 1 or 2, it was an inbuilt implementation of the owner who provided the data.

Comment: It doesn't matter who labelled it as 1 or 2. Because, it doesn't matter if it is labelled 1 or 2, or "apple" and "banana", or anything else. Mode regression does not depend on the labels in the data.